# No default service level objective found of edition "GeneralPurpose"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am getting this error `No default service level objective found of edition "GeneralPurpose"` in `SSMS` when creating database in `Azure SQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download the latest SQL Server Management Studio version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). Version 18.0 has many fixes related to Azure Managed Instances.

It is a limitation of the free subscription you are using at this time. ""'Free Trial subscriptions can provision Basic, Standard S0 through S3 databases, up to 100 eDTU Basic or Standard elastic pools and DW100 through DW400 data warehouses"

You can also try to create the database using T-SQL as shown below.

```
CREATE DATABASE Testdb
( EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S3' );
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for help. when i run your T-SQL i get this error message "'Free Trial subscriptions can provision Basic, Standard S0 through S3 databases, up to 100 eDTU Basic or Standard elastic pools and DW100 through DW400 data warehouses"

Comment: I changed the CREATE statement please run it as shown above. Due to limitations of your free trial subscription you cannot create databases on the premium tier and above S3 Standard tier.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had wrong connection string in my app settings(.NET).

To find your connection string you need to go to your db on azure and in overview you need to find "connection string".